# Pass a bean in a dialog with Dialog Framework in Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, parameters, frameworks, dialog, javabeans

I have some problem to pass a entire bean in a dialog.
I would like to open a dialog with Dialog Framework in Primefaces, and pass the method and attributes content in bean.
I tried to make this code, but it don't work.How should I do?

```
<p:commandButton value="open dialog" ajax="true"
                actionListener="#{processController.openSelectFieldDialog}"  
                update="tableResult , :notificationForm:info-messages">
                <f:attribute name="controller" value="#{processController}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This is the code inside openSelectFieldDialog method:

```
public void openSelectFieldDialog(){
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("genericSelectFieldDialog");
}
```

And this is the code inside the dialog controller:

```
public void onload() {
    Object somethingBean= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("controller");
}
```

I understand that i pass parameters on openDialog method, but i don't find any example on primefaces site. Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: What are you ytrying to do here?

Comment: I trying to pass some list that are will be rendered in a table and some method that will be used in dialog page

Comment: The list is a list of object and not a list of string.

Comment: When reverse engineering in netbeans it creates something like this instead: <p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.prepareSomething}" update="dialogId" oncomplete="PF('dialogWidgetVar').show()" />

Comment: You can pull `controller` only from `openSelectFieldDialog`. Where is `onload` being called?